# how to use reducerrors method to handle errors in lightning web component?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, salesforce, lwc

[image: Can Anyone expain please why did we write ": [ ] " in line 10]

Can Anyone explain please why did we write ": [ ] " in line 10. I believe it is the simplest way to write but what exactly is this, can anyone give another example of this to understand please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to look at lines 9 and 10 together. It's just a `?:` [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

If there are errors - use helper function (it probably flattens various error messages, page level, field level, duplicate rules etc) to get 1 simple error message.

Else return an empty array.

Comment: Great I understood now. Thanks @eyescream